# How to define a contentType of file association in Eclipse using a regular Expression

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am implementing an editor which specializes an existing Editor (The Java Properties file editor) in Eclipse.

My editor should be used instead of the 'general' editor only for certain files. The names of these files can be recognized as matching a pattern "application*.properties". For example

- "application.properties"
- "application-prod.properties"
- "application-test.properties"
- ...

When the filename does not match the pattern then the regular properties file editor should be used.

I tried creating a new content-type and associate that with my editor. I can get this to work if I associate the content-type explicitly with exact file names... like this:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
  <content-type
        ...
        file-names="application.properties,application-test.properties,application-prod.properties"
  </content-type>
</extension>
```

What I really wanted to is this, but it does not work:

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.core.contenttype.contentTypes">
  <content-type
        ...
        file-names="application*.properties"
  </content-type>
</extension>
```

Is there a way to define content types that match more generally to regular-expression or glob patterns rather than just recognizing them based on an exactly matching filename or extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. You can still add *.properties to your editor's declared list of file associations and choose to open it from a file's "Open With..." context menu.

Comment: Yeah, after digging through the source code for the 'org.eclipse.core.contenttype' plugin I figured that its not possible. The best 'solution' I've come up with so far is adding a context menu to '*.properties' files to 'enable' the editor. What this does is add a file association based on the resource's name. Not an ideal solution but I don't have any better ideas. (Always using 'open as' isn't convenient, and I don't think all users would realize they can add a file association by themselves to avoid this.

Comment: Ironically, you can define a ContentDescriber to content type. This allows determining type based on file contents. But it doesn't have access to the actual, name or path of the underlying resource. So unfortunately won't let me match on arbitrary file name patterns. But it does allow matching on arbitrary stuff in the file content.